# Healthy amount of threads and tasks?

Tags: linux

I am experiencing heavy amounts of lag in VSCode and other processes. In the picture below, is this a healthy amount of threads and tasks? At times the tasks will go over 100 and threads generally stay around 500.

[HTop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79jOV.png)

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               55
Model name:          Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N2830  @ 2.16GHz
Stepping:            8
CPU MHz:             2415.701
CPU max MHz:         2415.7000
CPU min MHz:         499.8000
BogoMIPS:            4333.08
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           24K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            1024K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome is hungry... It is him whom needs a huge amount of threads.
It will be okay. Try closing chrome or are least some tabs.

It needs one thread per tab + one thread per plugin !

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case, I have a ton of extensions but I have not had any issues till recently. 

I'm going to do some tests and post back.

Comment: This seemed to fix it. Disabled a lot of my extensions (RIP extensions) and the lag has gone. He whom is hungry loses his extensions.

Comment: Happy i could've help you ! Feel free to accept the answer and close the topic